# Django. How to display image in template

Tags: python, django

How to display image in template?

I try something like this (but doesn't work):

This is my model:

```
from django.db import models

class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/galery")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Galery"
        verbose_name_plural = "Galery"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

from kolejny.galery.models import Photo

def photo(request):
    photos = Photo.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('photo.html', {'photos' : photos}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

photo.html

```
{% for p in photos  %}
<img src="{{ p.img.url }}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^photo/$', 'galery.views.photo'),
    url(r'^site_media/(.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root' : os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'site_media')}),
)
```

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What output are you getting?  Can you be a little more descriptive about what isn't working?  Are you 404-ing the image, are you getting a syntax error, etc etc...

Answer (score 4):

set your MEDIA_ROOT variable to point to the folder where the actual images are, like:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'site_media')
```

and the line in urls.py to point to the same folder:

```
url(r'^site_media/(.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root' : settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

and MEDIA_URL:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/site_media/'
```